# regex: don't match if containing a specific string

Tags: regex

I have two strings:

```
"Some Stuff S00E00 HDTV x264-2HD mp4"

"Some Stuff S00E00 720p HDTV X264"
```

And this regex:

```
^.ome.*.tuff.*.(mp4.*|HDTV.*|x264.*)
```

What I need is to only match the first one. So if the string contains "720" the regex should not match that. But the string has to contain "mp4", "HDTV" or "x264".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your chosen language / platform supports it, you can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), like this:

```
^(?!.*720).ome.*.tuff.*.(mp4.*|HDTV.*|x264.*)
```

But this can be further simplified to:

```
^(?!.*720).ome.*tuff.*(mp4|HDTV|x264).*
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%3F!.%2a720%29.ome.%2atuff.%2a%28mp4%7CHDTV%7Cx264%29.%2a&input=Some%20Stuff%20S00E00%20HDTV%20x264-2HD%20mp4%0A%0ASome%20Stuff%20S00E00%20720p%20HDTV%20X264)