# RegEx lookahead but not immediately following

Tags: regex

I am trying to match terms such as the Dutch ge-berg-te. `berg` is a noun by itself, and ge...te is a circumfix, i.e. `geberg` does not exist, nor does `bergte`. `gebergte` does. What I want is a RegEx that matches `berg` or `gebergte`, working with a lookaround. I was thinking this would work

```
\b(?i)(ge(?=te))?berg(te)?\b
```

But it doesn't. I am guessing because a lookahead only checks the immediate following characters, and not across characters. Is there any way to match characters with a lookahead withouth the constraint that those characters have to be immediately behind the others?

**Valid** matches would be:

- Berg
- berg
- Gebergte
- gebergte

**Invalid** matches could be:

- Geberg
- geberg
- Bergte
- bergte

ge-/Ge- and -te always have to occur *together*. Note that I want to try this with a lookahead. I know it can be done simpler, but I want to see if its methodologically possible to do something like this.

Comment: Can you provide a list of valid and invalid matches?

Comment: How generic do you want it, and does your regex implementation support variable width lookahead & behind assertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one non-lookaround based regex:

```
\b(berg|gebergte)\b
```

Use it with `i` (ignore case) flag. This regex uses alternation and word boundary to search for complete words `berg` OR `gebergte`.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pG5lJ6/1)

Lookaround based regex:

```
(?<=\bge)berg(?=te\b)|\bberg\b
```

This regex used a lookahead and lookbehind to search for `berg` preceded by `ge` and followed by `te`. Alternatively it matches complete word `berg` using word boundary asserter `\b` which is also 0-width asserter like anchors `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 0):

To generally forbid a sign, you can put the negative lookaround to the beginning of a string and combine it with random number of other signs before the string you want to forbid:
[regex: don't match if containing a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096240/regex-dont-match-if-containing-a-specific-string)

```
^(?!.\*720).*
```

This will not match, if the string contains `720`, but else match everything else.